# Executing synchronous/asynchronous algorithms from the same list

Tags: c#, async-await

Say I had a list of algorithms, some of which had an async call in their body and others did not but I want to execute them all by iterating a list same time as below. The order in which I execute the algorithms is the order in which I want to receive the results. That is, I want the AlgorithmResult List to look like {Algorithm1Result, Algorithm2Result, Algorithm3Result} after all the algorithms have executed.

In order to do so I have to mark the synchronous Algorithm with the async keyword even though there will be no corresponding await in it's body, so I'm presuming that will just be treated as synchronous.

Is there a cleaner way to complete the above as it's odd seeing the async keyword with no await.....all because I want to execute synchronous/asynchronous algorithms together and receive the results in order.

```
var algorithms = new List<Algorithm>(){Algorithm1, Algorithm2, Algorithm3};
var algorithmResults = new List<AlgorithmResults>();

 foreach (var algorithm in algorithms)
 {
    algorithmResults.Add(await algorithm.Execute());
 }
```

Comment: `I have to mark the synchronous Algorithm with the async keyword` - don't mark, just return Task.FromResult(algResult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing parallel and asynchronous programming. When you `await` a `Task`, you are doing sequential work asynchronously. This code does not allow you to run multiple algorithms at the same time.
A common way to fulfill the interface/base class is to use `Task.FromResult`:

```
public class Algorithm1 : IAlgorithm
{
    // asynchronous algorithm
    public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync() => await ...;
}

public class Algorithm2 : IAlgorithm
{
    // synchronous algorithm
    public Task<int> ExecuteAsync()
    {
        int result = ...;

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

And you can consume them just the same way:

```
foreach (var algorithm in algorithms)
{
    algorithmResults.Add(await algorithm.ExecuteAsync());
}
```